# 1st line is landscape mode

Tags: indentation

I want some text to appear as below:

[image]

The code I have written for it is :

```
\begin{landscape}
Design Summary (This page shows how to use landscape format in Appendix.)\\
\texttt{---------}\\
Design Summary:\\
Number of errors: 0\\
Number of warnings: 0\\
Logic Utilization:\\
Number of Slice Flip Flops: 3,899 out of 33,280 11\%\\
Number of 4 input LUTs: 3,717 out of 33,280 11\%\\
Logic Distribution:\\
Number of occupied Slices: 2,198 out of 16,640 13\%\\
Number of Slices containing only related logic: 2,198 out of 2,198 100\%\\
Number of Slices containing unrelated logic: 0 out of 2,198 0\%\\
*See NOTES below for an explanation of the effects of unrelated logic.\\
Total Number of 4 input LUTs: 3,890 out of 33,280 11\%\\

\end{landscape}
```

The output I am getting is as below:

[image]

In my output, the word design summary in the 1st line is starting after a couple of spaces. I need it to start from extreme left as can be seen in the 1st picture. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Add `\noindent` at the very beginning.

Comment: This is unrelated to landscape, it's simply the start of a paragraph.